# In clickhouse, how can I separate number by comma?

Tags: clickhouse

In clickhouse, how can I separate number by comma?

```
select toString(toDecimal64(roundBankers( 12321.121 ,  1 ),  1 ))
```

and returns 12,321.1 instead of 12321.1, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such formatting to strings from numbers is not implemented.

```
select formatReadableQuantity(roundBankers( 12321.121 ,  1 ));
┌─formatReadableQuantity(roundBankers(12321.121, 1))─┐
│ 12.32 thousand                                     │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

```
SELECT concat(toString(intDiv(roundBankers(12321.121, 1) AS x, 1000)), ',', toString(x % 1000)) AS r
┌─r─────────────────────┐
│ 12,321.10000000000036 │
└───────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

For Integer data type, you can try

```html
create function formatNumberReadable on cluster cluster_3S_2R as (number) -> reverse(if(number < 1000, reverse(toString(number)),
                  if(number between 1000 and 999999,
                     concat(substr(reverse(toString(number)), 1, 3), ',',
                            substr(reverse(toString(number)), 4, length(toString(number)))),
                     if(number between 1000000 and 999999999,
                        concat(substr(reverse(toString(number)), 1, 3), ',', substr(reverse(toString(number)), 4, 3),
                               ',',
                               substr(reverse(toString(number)), 7, length(toString(number)))),
                        if(number between 1000000000 and 999999999999,
                           concat(substr(reverse(toString(number)), 1, 3), ',', substr(reverse(toString(number)), 4, 3),
                                  ',',
                                  substr(reverse(toString(number)), 7, 3), ',',
                                  substr(reverse(toString(number)), 10, 3)),
                           reverse(toString(number))
                            )
                         )
                      )
    )
    );

select formatNumberReadable(123456789);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)